# Plotting value from QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, classification

I am attempting to follow the scikit-learn documentation but can't find a useful example to follow. I have a data set of n samples and 6 features, currently stored in a numpy array X. I have another array, Y, of the classes (2) that each sample belongs to. I have used EmpiricalCovariance to compute the covariance estimates for each class as well as computed the means for each. I want to use QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis to plot a quadratic classifier for these values and plot it across an arbitrary two-dimensional projection of the data. I am unsure how to complete this task.

Comment: 1. `QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis` does not support dimensionality reduction to *project your data into a lower (affine) subspace*. Check `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis` instead. With two classes, you can project your data to a line only.
2. `QuadraticDiscriminantAnalysis` does not support custom covariance estimates like `EmpiricalCovariance`. Again, refer to `LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(shrinkage=None)`.

Comment: @SanjarAdylov So if I were to instead compute the covariance and means myself, and plot the data points. How could I find and plot a quadratic classifier curve over these data points? I am open to using any library that allows for a quadratic classifier.

Comment: This tutorial plots decision boundaries and covariance ellipsoids https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_lda_qda.html . Considering custom covariance estimation for QDA, I'm not aware of any package supporting such feature.